# How to give input to System.in via a .in file in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a very large input set that I want to give to a small Java program I'm trying to debug, but I'm lost on how to accomplish this. My program reads in data via a Scanner reading System.in

giving the command line argument in Run under Project Properties does not seem to work. I give it "< testfile.in" and it interprets it as two values in args[]. I need it to interpret this as reading the file as System.in

edit: my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ifp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numCities = ifp.nextInt();
    for(int c=0; c<numCities; c++){
        int intersections = ifp.nextInt();
        int streets = ifp.nextInt();

        destination = intersections-1;
        ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Edge> negEdges =  new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<streets; i++){
            int start = ifp.nextInt();
            int end = ifp.nextInt();
            int distance = ifp.nextInt();
            Edge temp = new Edge(start, end, distance);
            edges.add(temp);
            temp = new Edge(start, end, -distance);
            negEdges.add(temp);
        }

        /* some shenanigans where I don't scan in anything */
    }
}
```

Comment: comment you code

Comment: Not sure how code would help for this question, but there you go

Comment: If you're talking about args[], I don't use it in this program. It's just there as included by Netbeans. If you mean where I'm trying to give the argument "< testfile.in", I'm trying under Run>Set Project Configuration>Customize... and putting the command in the arguments box. I'm not sure where else I can specify command-line arguments.

Comment: Why not declare a file object inside the scanner with the appropriate file path? Like this -> new Scanner(new File("/Path.")

Comment: The same way it runs when called via the command prompt. If you call a compiled java program in the command line with "< testfile.in > testfile.out" then it will act as if someone is typing in all the stuff in testfile.in to the command line and, instead of outputting to the command line, it will output the text to testfile.out. That is what I want to do in debugging my program via Netbeans.